# Ignoring case in Pyspark while data filtering

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe(input_dataframe), data in this dataframe looks like as below:

```
id              value
 1                Ab
 2                Ai
 3                aB
```

I want to select data where value is **ab**(case should not matter)
Below is the code, i am using for same:

```
input_dataframe.where(col('value').isin("ab"))
```

But id does not fetch me desired output. Can someone help me with it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at `pyspark.sql.functions.lower(col)`
in your case this should be something like:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
input_dataframe.where(sf.lower(sf.col('value')).isin("ab"))
```

Comment: Isn't a closing parenthesis `)` unwanted before `.isin`?

Comment: nope, you want to check isin after applying `lower`